# How to disable the delivered Hyperlink in PeopleSoft org chart page?

Tags: peoplesoft

Can anybody suggest a method to disable the hyperlinks associated with the names on the PeopleSoft delivered org chart page?
Peoplesoft HR module, Company Directory Org Chart page (`HRCD_ORG_CHART_FL`)

Comment: What PeopleSoft module (e.g. Human Capital Management, Campus Solutions, etc.)? Navigation? Menu/Component/Page name? I don't know if this is a "normal" PeopleSoft page, but if it is you can probably modify the page definition to hide the hyperlink. If it's a complicated page (probably) then the information I asked for would be useful for anyone who wanted to take a look for themselves.

Comment: Peoplesoft HR module, Company Directory Org Chart page

Comment: What menu name/component/ namepage name are displayed when you press control+shift+j in your browser?

Comment: Delivered peoplesoft page hrcd_org_chart_fl